# Basic JQuery Question

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, selector, document-ready

I have the following JQuery code that processes a GET request upon page load:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  var refreshId = setInterval(function()
  {
       $('#tweets').fadeOut("slow").fadeIn("slow");
       $.get("/event", { event:$("input[name=event]").val(), }, function(data) {
         console.log(data.success);
         console.log(data.page_link);
         console.log('Succesfully Loaded Data from JSON FORMAT GET');
         $('#tweets').html(data.html);
         $('#pagelink').html(data.page_link);
       });

  }, 30000); 
});
```

The problem is I would like this GET request to be processed only on a specific page. My application loads all JQuery files at once, in an application.js file. How can I use JQuery to specify, something other than document ready and what would an ideal selector be?

Comment: You can always use location.href to check if the user is on the page you'd like to make the request on.

Comment: How do you want to identify the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a `class` to the body tag.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  if ($('body').hasClass('updateTweets')) {
  var refreshId = setInterval(function()
  {
       $('#tweets').fadeOut("slow").fadeIn("slow");
       $.get("/event", { event:$("input[name=event]").val(), }, function(data) {
         console.log(data.success);
         console.log(data.page_link);
         console.log('Succesfully Loaded Data from JSON FORMAT GET');
         $('#tweets').html(data.html);
         $('#pagelink').html(data.page_link);
       });

  }, 30000); 
  }
});
```

Comment: This is great, but I'm using rails framework and all body's are the same. Would it work if I simply added a <p> tag with a specific class on a page, and tested for this?

Answer (score 2):

You could do a conditional based on the existence of an element that only exists on the page you want your code to fire.

Copied from another question:

```
jQuery.fn.exists = function()
{
    return jQuery(this).length > 0;
}

if ($(selector).exists())
{
    // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you just include the code on the one page you want it run on?

Somewhere between the `<html>` tag you can have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
[...code...]
</script>
```

With the code in your question between the `<script>` tags.

Comment: I could but I don't want to. This is a large web app, that has a well organized file structure.

Comment: @JZ, I would argue, that a large web app that has code that should only fire for one page, but is included for all, is NOT well organized at all.

Comment: A slightly cleaner solution would be to move this function to its own javascript file and only include it on that page. Neil, are you following me :S ?

Answer (score 1):

Check the file location with `window.location.href` then use an ifstatement:

```
if(window.location.href == 'whatever.html'){
    $(document).ready(function() { 
           ...
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the `location` property to find out which page you're in.

You can also check for the existence of an element:

```
if ($("something").length)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this way of organizing your app.js

http://weblogs.asp.net/jaimedelpalacio/archive/2011/03/23/a-way-to-organize-your-javascript-code.aspx